# LimeSurvey: anyway to use get_session_key , JSON-RPC with Authwebserver?

Tags: json, api, rpc, limesurvey

I'm trying to integrate LimeSurvey with my own web server through its API. My own web server has its own usernames and passwords, and my  web server needs to authenticate a user through the API.

Is there a way to call the LimeSurvey get_session_key API (JSON-RPC), but not use AuthDB? (I can't use AuthLDAP). Is there a way to use, for example, Authwebserver, instead, using the Authwebserver plugin, to allow my web server to authenticate a user over the JSON-RPC API?

The following ***does not*** work:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://mysurveyserver/index.php/admin/remotecontrol' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --header 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 
--data-raw '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "get_session_key",
    "params": [
        "username@email.com",
        "anydummypassword",
        "Authwebserver"
    ],
    "id": 1
}'
```

This sends back a response saying:

```
{"id":1,"result":{"status":"Invalid user name or password"},"error":null}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry to ask. Do usernames and passwords live in limesurvey webserver? Is the authwebserver plugin active and configured? Not a keen on authwebserver, but I would check in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way currently to authenticate via webserver.

You can try to construct your own system, need to regsiter to [remoteControlLogin](https://manual.limesurvey.org/Authentication_plugin_development#remoteControlLogin) .

Currently [Authwebserver](https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/master/application/core/plugins/Authwebserver/Authwebserver.php) plugin are not compatible with API. But remind : how you sedn information about authentification ? Since your webserver authenticate itself : you must authenticate on the same way, and LimeSurvey didn't know how you currently authenticate by webserver …